# Why is the Seed method called again in my EF code first migrations scenario?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a EF code first project and there is how I seed the database

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<myDB>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            ContextKey = "myDB.Auth.Service.DAL.myDB";
        }

        protected override void Seed(myDBdb)
        {
           var mProduct = new Product
             {
                Name = "default product",
               CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            };

           db.Products.AddOrUpdate(mProduct);
           db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

I have a wcf service that uses above code. What I realise is that every time I restart the wcf service (either from visual studio or IIS), above code is get called. As a result, multiple "default product" are added into the database, anyone knows why that happened?

Comment: Did you find a valid answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Migration seed runs after every update-database so you need to make your script idempotent by testing for existance or using AddOrUpdate. If you only want to seed on database creation, there is a separate context seed method that only runs when the database is created.

https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

[AddOrUpdate for seeding](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/)

Edit:

When you use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer, your seed method runs every time your application runs. If you want to control this process, switch your initializer to null:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

And then just manually run migrations when needed. To take it a step further, you can write your own initializer and do what you want when either the database does not exist or the database needs updating:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new ValidateDbInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>());

// ref: https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/
public class ValidateDbInitializer<TContext> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
    where TContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The database does not exist. Check your server and connection string.");
        }
        if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The database is not up to date. You may need to apply update(s).");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, looks like everytime my wcf service is restarted (either by visual studio or iis), the initilization process is called. Is there a way to tell why is that?

Answer (score 1):

First step is to use the Tools menu, select Library Package Manager, then select Package Manager Console. In the Package Manager Console window  type the below command.

```
  Enable-Migrations
```

which will adds folder named as Migrations in your project and also a code file called as Configuration.cs.

in Configuration.cs type the below line

using yourprojectname.Models;

```
protected override void Seed(yourprojectname.Models.MyServiceContext context)
{
   context.MyDB.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
    new MyData() {  Name = "Mohit",   CreatedDate= "14/05/2016" },
    new MyData() {  Name = "Prabhat", CreatedDate= "15/05/2016" },

    );  
 }
```

Now type    Update-Database
   in Package Manager Console window

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
protected override void Seed(myDBdb)
{
    var mProduct = new Product
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "default product",
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    db.Products.AddOrUpdate(mProduct);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the application for initialization the Data for the first time, please use `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`. e.g. :

```
public class MyClass : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<connectionstringContextName>
{
     protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
     {
         // Your seed data
     }
}
```

Comment: but the database is already there, (the first time I run the code the database was created with the right seed data). Shouldn't entity framework find that automatically?